# What does it mean if the icon beside my mq4 expert advisor is gray?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I have written an mq4 expert advisor: donat_chart_test. In MetaTrader4 I see that the icon beside it is gray. The expert advisor works fine.

[image]

What does it mean if the icon beside the expert advisor is gray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I found out. It means that I put only the compiled `*.ex4` file into the `<MetaTrader>/experts` directory, not the `*.mq4` source.